# Resource allocation problem

Tags: algorithm

I was trying to solve some problems from ACM Problem Set. I stumbled upon one interesting which was too difficult for me.

Detailed information: http://www.karrels.org/Ed/ACM/93/prob_g.html

For me it looks like we have d baskets (one basket for each division) and a set of possible options in each basket (one option for each possible allocation). Each possible option is like knapsack item with two parameters (money and programmers). Both parameters are limited to values b and p respectively.

Please give me some idea about how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a dynamic programming problem to me.  Basically, you want to approach each division in sequence: maintain a set of the best available solutions for the divisions already considered, then add the remaining divisions one by one.

Specifically:  you can combine two option matrices (as described for each division) into a combined option matrix.  The rows and columns for this matrix are all possible sums of the rows and columns of the original matrices, and the payoff entries are the sum of the payoffs in the original matrices.  Note that it is possible for rows and columns to overlap (if two sums end up being the same); in that case you clearly want to use the largest payoff.  Also, you will need to store how each payoff was achieved, so you can eventually report how to achieve the optimum solution.

Note that, if the sizes of the original matrices are A and B, the size of resulting matrix could be O(A*B) in the worst case.  However, you don't need to store any rows or columns that are larger than the total available resources.  Also, as previously noted, rows and columns will be combined if there is more than one way to reach that sum.  Finally, I believe you can drop any matrix entries whose payoffs are no better than other matrix entries that require less resources; the resulting sparse matrices may take much less space and computation to deal with.

In any case, once you've combined all your divisions into one final matrix, report the largest payoff entry as your solution.

Comment: But if I understand you correctly, after processing first division we get 100 possible options in worst case; after second it would be 100*100, so after 20 we get 100^20. It's too large, I think

Comment: Yes, depending in the problem, worst case for dynamic programming can be exponential.  However, in practice it is often tractable; in particular, eliminating dominated solutions (the sparse matrix bit above) can be especially effective.  In any case, a dynamic programming framework should actually solve the problem (which is a decent first step), and may serve as a starting point for finding a better solution; unfortunately, I don't see an obvious solution to the problem that is much better.